# Baryon Number Conservation

Tags: symmetry, conservation-laws, noethers-theorem, baryons

To my understanding, every conservation law is associated with some continuous symmetry in the relevant theory. Then what is the symmetry associated with the conservation of Baryon number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conservation of baryon number $B=(n_q-n_{\bar{q}})/3$, where $n_q$ denotes the number of quarks and $n_{\bar{q}}$ the number of antiquarks, has its origin in the global $U(1)_V$ symmetry $q \to e^{i \alpha} q$ of the standard model, acting on the quark fields $q= u, d, c, s, t, b$.